# Pluralis Majestatis?

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-case, article

[image]

Lässt sich bei dieser Widmungsgravur der Artikel "den" vor *Kaiser* durch Pluralis Majestatis erklären?
Wenn so, warum steht dann auch nicht *seiner Majestät* in Plural (seinen Majestäten)?

Ich habe hier noch einen Beleg für die Richtigkeit der Schreibweise gefunden:

[Google-Books – PhilippCharwarth: "Der Untergang einer mittelmaßigen Macht, die Großmacht sein wollte"](https://books.google.com/books?id=VUVVKrU28FoC&lpg=PA146&dq=%22geschenk%20von%20seiner%20majest%C3%A4t%20den%22&hl=sv&pg=PA146)

Und noch weitere Belege findet sich mit einer einfachen Googlesuche. Ein Fehler bei der Gravur ist das sicher nicht.

Comment: Seit wann ist _**den**_ Plural?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Wie meinst du das? Plural Dativ ist wohl "den"? Oder bin ich verwirrt und sollte aufhören deutsch zu studieren?

Comment: Ich halte das eher für einen Fehler in der Gravur und es hätte _dem Kaiser_ heißen müssen.

Comment: @Beta ^ Dies hier!

Comment: @Marzipanherz denkst du dass der Graveur seine Stellung behalten durfte? So einen Fehler halte ich aber persöhnlich bei diesem Objekt für sehr unwahrscheinlich.

Comment: @Marzipanherz  Hier noch ein Beleg für die Richtigkeit der Schreibweise: https://books.google.se/books?id=VUVVKrU28FoC&pg=PA146&lpg=PA146&dq=%22geschenk+von+seiner+majest%C3%A4t+den%22&source=bl&ots=2-yjlttQxn&sig=jBjMlxSJsBwBv2YDKJquZWwZ9_4&hl=sv&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjW5JOij5_bAhXFI1AKHWB0ClsQ6AEwAHoECAEQKw#v=onepage&q=%22geschenk%20von%20seiner%20majest%C3%A4t%20den%22&f=false

Comment: @Beta Witzig, der selbe Satz wird in zwei anderen Quellen mit "dem" zitiert: https://www.google.se/search?tbm=bks&hl=sv&q=%22geschenk+von+seiner+majest%C3%A4t+dem%22

Comment: Vielleicht hatte es der Graveur ähnlich eilig wie der beim DFB-Pokal? Da kann so etwas schon passieren. Nach meinem Sprachgefühl müßte da auch _dem_ stehen.

Comment: @Marzipanherz nein das ist nicht witzig. Die erklärung liegt darin, dass nur der Kaiser selbst die PM verwendete, nicht andere leute, wenn sie ihn zitierten

Comment: @0xC0000022L  Ich denke du kannst nicht von deinem Sprachgefühl ausgehen. Die Ausdruckweise ist ja eher etwas "datiert"  :)

Comment: @Beta Im von Dir verlinkten Buch wird über eine Anna geschrieben, die eine Erklärung unterschreiben musste, dass sie ein Geschenk vom Kaiser erhalten hat. Der Wortlaut der Erklärung wird im von Dir verlinkten Buch genau so wieder gegeben, wie in den von mir verlinkten - nur mit dem Unterschied, dass er mal mit _dem_ und mal mit _den_ geschrieben wird. An keiner Stelle redet der Kaiser von sich, so dass wir den PM für dieses Beispiel ausschließen können, denke ich.

Comment: Was ist auf dem Bild, wo kommts her, Histörchen dazu, etc? Tendiere auch zu [Fehler](https://books.google.de/books?id=-D1NAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA170&lpg=RA1-PA170&dq=%22von+seiner+majestät+den%22&source=bl&ots=CFl8q42JZI&sig=Ii0wh3XGcsUfaN3FocIs-gqAoIU&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSofGNm5_bAhVMZ1AKHTKuDDsQ6AEIRzAI#v=onepage&q=%22von%20seiner%20majestät%20den%22&f=false) Beleg in gBooks ist fast immer Fraktur-m als n OCRed.

Comment: Ist es nicht ohnehin so, daß in dem gezeigten Spruch kein Pluralis Majestatis Verwendung findet? Wäre das nicht wahlweise die Rede des Kaisers in Form von "wir" und "uns"? [Laut Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Majestaet) scheint selbst "Eure Majestät" als Anrede keine Pluralform zu sein.

Comment: Mit einer Googlesuche findet man aber auch zahlreiche Belege (Text und Bild), die eine grammatikalisch korrekte Form enthalten. Es scheint tatsächlich ein Fehler des Graveuers (oder des Auftraggebers) zu sein.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Die Gravur ist fehlerhaft. Jedenfalls mit äußerst großer Wahrscheinlichkeit, wie wir uns erlauben zu behaupten.

Richtig hieße es:

> Geschenk von Seiner Majestät de**m** Kaiser Wilhelm II
>   <sub>Der wahrscheinlich in Auftrag gegebene Text.</sub>

Eine Pluralform könnte so lauten:

> Geschenk von Ihren Majestäten de**n** Kaisern Wilhelm I & II
>   <sub>Das bekannte Dualkaisertum aus einem unserer alternativgeschichtlichen Universen: Opa und Enkel beide schlank genug geblieben, um gemeinsam auf einem Thron zu sitzen.</sub>

Zur Begründung könnte man einige Argumente anführen:

1. Gravurfehler treten immer wieder auf. Auch heute noch mit Lasertechnik. In einem Szenario, dass den Reisekaiser unterwegs sein lässt, als es ihm in seiner Spontanität gefällt, einem Herrn Noth schnell ein kleines personalisiertes Geschenk zukommen zu lassen, ist es denkbar, dass er nicht seinen Haus- und Hofgraveur in Berlin beauftragt, sondern einen kleinen Handwerker vor Ort. Dieser Handwerker hatte vielleicht wenig Erfahrung mit höfischen Umgangsformen Anreden und Titeln, und vielleicht sogar Probleme mit Grammatik allgemein. Vielleicht wurde das Stück auf einer Auslandsreise in Auftrag gegeben. Das eingravierte Datum deutet ferner ebenfalls darauf hin, dass zwischen Weihnachten und Jahresende eine gewisse Feierlaune, oder Notbesetzung im Betrieb oder Restalkohol involviert gewesen sein könnten. Fehler passieren auch bei Münzprägungen, bei Einzelstücken ist sowas keinesfalls ausgeschlossen. Manche Fehler entwickeln sich sogar zu einer hübschen Tradition, wie das [Wappen der Stadt Bruchsal illustriert](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruchsal#Wappen).
2. Auch aus typographischer Sicht ist diese Gravur nicht von höchster Qualität. Das "v." ist nach unten verrutscht und das "j" aus Majestät probt schon mal Weltkrieg mit dem "W" aus Wilhelm. Insgesamt wirken die Buchstaben wenig harmonisch und unregelmäßig, gequetscht oder gestreckt. Beachten Sie bitte auch die rechte Seite des N in Noth und den verrutschten Punkt, wieder auf dem j von Majestät.
3. Bislang angeführte "Belege" für die Verbreitung und eventuelle "Richtigkeit" der hier vorgefundenen Schreibweise sind keine.
   Bei einer Suche nach der Wortfolge "von seiner majestät den" findet Google Books tatsächlich eine beachtliche Anzahl von Treffern. Bei näherer Untersuchung handelt es sich aber um alte, von Google digitalisierte Bücher, die im Original in gebrochener Schrift gesetzt waren. Die Digitaltextebene wurde per Schrifterkennung hinzugefügt und liefert die Trefferliste aus der Suchmaschinendatenbank oder beim Download eines PDFs. Die Schrifterkennung war jedoch fehlerhaft und repräsentiert regelmäßig ein "n" wo jeder Mensch deutlich ein Fraktur-"m" erkennt. Wenn in letzter Zeit Texte digital neu erstellt werden und aus Unterlagen und Büchern aus diesem Fundus zitieren, dann geschieht dies per copy&paste – aus der fehlerhaften Digitaltextebene.
   Für die Verwendung eines Konstrukts "von seiner majestät dem" fanden sich keine Belege in zeitgenössischen Büchern bei Untersuchung der Texte mit menschlichen Augen. Beispiel:

   > [image]
   >   [image]
   >   eines von zahlreichen Beispielen via [Google Books](https://books.google.de/books?id=-D1NAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA170&lpg=RA1-PA170&dq=%22von%20seiner%20majest%C3%A4t%20den%22&source=bl&ots=CFl8q42JZI&sig=Ii0wh3XGcsUfaN3FocIs-gqAoIU&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSofGNm5_bAhVMZ1AKHTKuDDsQ6AEIRzAI#v=onepage&q=%22von%20seiner%20majest%C3%A4t%20den%22&f=false)

Comment: _ das "j" aus Majestät probt schon mal Weltkrieg mit dem "W"_ You made my day :D

Comment: Scheint plausibel. Aber wie könnte man so einen Fehler erklären? ?Es handelt sich um eine feine Taschenuhr vom Hoflieferanten Eppner in Berlin. Der Graveur müsste eine andere muttersprache als Deutsch gehabt haben.  Oder?

Comment: @Beta Es könnte auch sein, dass der Beschenkte den Text dem Graveur so vorgegeben hat und der exakt das Bestellte graviert hat. Dann hätte der Beschenkte den Fehler begangen, was ja auch öfters vorkommt.

Comment: @Beta "Hoflieferant" ist allerdings interessant. Noch mehr infos verfügbar? Denn Uhrenhersteller (oder Lieferant) und Graveur müssen ja nicht identisch sein. (Neben den oben schon angeführten Gründen würde selbst bei Eppner noch eine gewisse Betriebsblindheit im "Fließbandbetrieb" möglich sein. Denke da an architecture fails und zahlreiche Bildersammlungen im Netz zu "Pfusch am Bau"…)

Comment: @Beta   Der Graveur war halt ein Graveur und kein Schulmeister, Schriftsteller oder Schriftsetzer oder sonstwie auf die Feinheiten des Grammatik getrimmter Sprachprofi.

Comment: @Beta Wenn du dich mal bei Texten aus heutiger Zeit umschaust, wirst du schnell feststellen, dass dieser eine Fehler in damaliger Zeit keiner Rede mehr Wert ist.

Comment: Beispiel aus jüngerer Zeit: https://www.tagesspiegel.de/weltspiegel/peinlicher-praegefehler-vatikan-entwirft-lesus-muenzen/8920224.html

Comment: @Beta, in Berlin hat man es bekanntlich nicht so mit Akkusativ und Dativ. http://www.berlin-lese.de/index.php?article_id=231

Comment: @CarstenS Dein Kommentar ist mir bisher die beste Antwort. Warum machst du daraus keine Antwort?

Comment: @Beta, ohne zu wissen, wer für den Text verantwortlich ist, ist das doch sehr spekulativ.